# How to sort a file based on a section of a field

Tags: text-processing, files, sort

I would like to sort a file :

```
   D104HN-D104HA      8.320      4.521   1.69e+05 -- 
   D104HN-D104HB*      8.320      2.823   2.93e+05 -- 
   A90HB#-A90HA      1.655      4.207   7.12e+05 -- 
   A90HB#-F91HA      1.653      4.411   8.59e+04 -- 
   A114HB#-A114HA      1.253      4.098   7.67e+05 -- 
   A114HB#-R111HA      1.251      3.929   1.76e+05 -- 
   A114HB#-W110HA      1.253      4.451   3.68e+04 -- 
   F91HE*-F91HZ      7.237      7.122   7.85e+05 -- 
     F91HE*-K92HA      7.242      3.910   4.88e+04 --
```

and get this

```
   A90HB#-A90HA      1.655      4.207   7.12e+05 -- 
   A90HB#-F91HA      1.653      4.411   8.59e+04 -- 
   F91HE*-F91HZ      7.237      7.122   7.85e+05 -- 
   F91HE*-K92HA      7.242      3.910   4.88e+04 -- 
   D104HN-D104HA      8.320      4.521   1.69e+05 -- 
   D104HN-D104HB*      8.320      2.823   2.93e+05 -- 
   A114HB#-A114HA      1.253      4.098   7.67e+05 -- 
   A114HB#-R111HA      1.251      3.929   1.76e+05 -- 
   A114HB#-W110HA      1.253      4.451   3.68e+04 --
```

That is, sort numerically on the second and following characters of the first sequence of non-blanks on the line.

Comment: apparently the editor didn't keep the format I used for the file....

Comment: Have you tried the `sort` command?

Comment: yes, but apparently I don't know how tu use it properly.... I tried :sort -b +0.1n -1    but also sort -n -k1,1 -k1,4 (and more others) but none of those worked

Comment: You want to sort according to the number starting from the second character?

Comment: exactly. the probleme is that in the file, there are different numbers of blank before the first field

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
sort -k 1.2bn < file
```

Sorts `n`umerically on a `k`ey starting with the `2`<sup>nd</sup> character of the `1`<sup>st</sup> field ignoring leading `b`lanks (and ending at the end of the line, but that doesn't matter for a numerical sort which only considers the initial sequence of decimal digits).

Note that if there's a tie, like in between these two lines:

```
    F91HE*-K92HA      7.242      3.910   4.88e+04 --
  F91HE*-F91HZ      7.237      7.122   7.85e+05 --
```

Then, the order will be based on the last-resort sort that compares the two lines fully as strings.

With some locales, blanks would be ignored in first instance for comparing strings in which case the F91 one would come before K92 (as `F` sorts before `K`). With others like in the C locale, blanks would not be ignored and the K92 would then come before the F91 one (space sorts before `F`).

For a last-resort sort that would ignore leading blanks regardless of the locale, you could do:

```
sort -k 1.2bn -k 1b < file
```

That `1b` one would sort (upon ties on the first key) lexically on the section of the line that starts with the first field ignoring leading blanks.